# WordPress Admin Protection Code

Tags: php, wordpress

I use a function on a WordPress site that prevents another admin from seeing the main admin account, the problem is that the other admin (client) can create users, and if they create another admin, then they will see the main admin, and if they see it, they may edit it or delete (this client has no technical skills and has caused similar problems before, I need to protect them from themselves).

Where it names "their" admin account, i.e. if ($username == 'client') { I want to change that so it captures all admin accounts except mine, in other word;s IF NOT adminrv (ultimately, I would like to show the main admin to 2 admins, myself and one other, so really; IF NOT adminrv AND adminba).

```
add_action('pre_user_query','yoursite_pre_user_query');
function yoursite_pre_user_query($user_search) {
  global $current_user;
  $username = $current_user->user_login;

  if ($username == 'client') { 
    global $wpdb;
    $user_search->query_where = str_replace('WHERE 1=1',
      "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.user_login != 'adminrv'",$user_search->query_where);
  }
}
```

Comment: I doubt whether this can be done in a sane and secure way. Does the client have to be an admin user? Why?

Comment: If anything ever happened to me, I can't leave a client high and dry without admin access to their own site.

Comment: This looks like what you are looking for http://marisaporter.com/keep-clients-from-creating-administrators/

Comment: If the client keeps disabling _your_ admin access, do they really want your services?

Comment: Who said their disabling my admin access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually pretty simple after reading a short PHP tutorial, I'm surprised no one here could answer this, maybe my question wasn't worded very well...

FROM

```
if ($username == 'client') {
```

TO

```
if ($username !== 'adminba') {
```